# git ignore doesn't work

Tags: git, laminas-api-tools

This might seem like a noob question but i couldn't find any solution to it. I have an apigility project cloned from the original repository. I have deleted the .git directory and kept the .gitignore file :

```
   nbproject
   ._*
   .~lock.*
   .buildpath
   .DS_Store
   .idea
   .project
   .settings
   composer.lock
   vendor/
   public/vendor/
   config/development.config.php
   config/autoload/local.php
   config/autoload/*.local.php
   !public/vendor/README.md
   data/cache/*
   !data/cache/.gitkeep
```

I have then made a "git init" in the root folder and my git repository was created. I have made a "git add .gitignore" and made an initial commit with it. After I tried to make a "git add ." but all my files are getting added to the staging area. I can't understand why because for example the .puppet directory is added to the .gitignore and it still gets added. I gave a shot to this solution [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository) it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: There is no `.puppet` directory listed in that `.gitignore` file...

Comment: it is maybe I forgot to paste it in the example. the composer.lock and the public/vendor can be considered valid examples as well.

Comment: Can you also include in your question (a) the output of `ls` in the top-level directory and (b) the output of `git status` after you have performed the `git add` operation?

Comment: In almost every case, composer.lock should be in your repository, not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is:

```
 yourrepo/
    .git/
    .gitignore
    yourfiles
```

Then a `git add .` would respect the `.gitignore`.
If not, a git rm --cached -- wrongfile would remove it from the index, and a `git status` would ignore it because of the `.gitignore`.